# How to interpret diagnostic plots for GEV distribution

Tags: diagnostic

I produced the following Diagnostic plots, from the following R Code:

```
library(evir)

library(ismev)

data(nidd.annual)

nidd.annual


nidd.annualgevfit=gev.fit(nidd.annual)

gev.diag(nidd.annualgevfit)
```

[image: Diagnostic Plots for GEV Distribution using MLE]

And am wondering how I am interpret these and whether the model is a good fit or if it is deficient in some respect?

My initial thoughts would be it's not too bad, as the majority of the points for both the Probability and Quantile plots are either on or close to the line, however not all of them are, especially near the top area of the quantile plot. There appears to be skew shown in the density plot, I believe. I am not sure about the return level plot, though.